# Where do I see what firefoxdriver selenium starts while testing?

Tags: testing, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have installed firebug for FF. But when i start firefox it always starts some default ff version, i dont' know where selenium finds it.

I already googled alot, tried to use different firefoxbinary:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");

  final File firefoxPath = new File(System.getProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin")) ;
  FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary=  new FirefoxBinary(firefoxPath);
  firefox = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary,null);
```

I tried to use different ff profile:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
   firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
   firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.9.1");
```

Alas, it does not work!
1. I don't know where to change/find webdriver.firefox.bin
2. I have tried changing path as environment variable,still no progress
maybe I m doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Selenium will open a "vanilla" Firefox profile.  If you want to have it launch with your profile, you can do that, but you have to select which profile you want to use. I will warn you that you often don't want to have your regular profile used because you'd like a clean, consistent working environment.

But you could certainly:

1. set up a profile (call it, for instance, selenium-profile using
   Firefox's profile manager
2. run Firefox choosing that profile--from
   Windows's Run dialog run "c:\Program Files(x86)\Mozilla
   Firefox\firefox.exe" - P"  or the equivalent path to FF if you are
   32-but.
3. install Firebug using that profile.
4. then choose that profile when you launch your tests.

For information about how to do all this, look at [this article](http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/custom-firefox-profile/).

Then, in your code, you can just call that profile. Step 3 in the article linked above shows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Firefoxdriver starts a new default profile on each instance and this profile will be created in your temp folder and will be deleted after you quit the driver.  There might be some old instances of ff profile which contains older version of firebug in your temp folder which might be not be deleted as webdriver quited unexpectedly.Try clearing your temp. It might help you as it did for me.